# Are unique indices on Access text fields always case insensitive?

Tags: delphi, ms-access, indexing

I created an MS Access table using the following code:

```
  tbl := Database.CreateTableDef('English', 0, '', '');
  try
    fld := tbl.CreateField('ID', dbLong, 0);
    fld.Attributes := dbAutoIncrField + dbFixedField;
    tbl.Fields.Append(fld);

    fld := tbl.CreateField('Content', dbText, 255);
    fld.Required := true;
    fld.AllowZeroLength := false;
    tbl.Fields.Append(fld);

    Database.TableDefs.Append(tbl);

    idx := tbl.CreateIndex('PrimaryKey');
    idx.Fields.Append(idx.CreateField('ID', EmptyParam, EmptyParam));
    idx.Primary := True;
    idx.Unique := true;
    tbl.Indexes.Append(idx);

    idx := tbl.CreateIndex('IX_Content');
    idx.Fields.Append(idx.CreateField('Content', EmptyParam, EmptyParam));
    idx.Primary := false;
    idx.Unique := true;
    tbl.Indexes.Append(idx);
  finally
    tbl := nil;
  end;
```

This works fine until I try to insert the two strings 'Field type' and 'Field Type' into this table. I get an error telling me that the unique index restricts me from doing that. As you can see they only differ in the case of the second word. Since I did not explicitly make the index case insensitive (I wouldn't even know how to do that), I don't quite understand why this happens. Are indices on text fields always case insensitive in MS Access? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access Jet databases are fundamentally case insensitive. That is your problem. As far as I know there is no way to make an Access index case sensitive.

Comment: Hm, of course after I read you answer, I found that mentioned on the internet quite a few times which is odd because I already tried to find a solution for hours. Just proves that using the Google requires some luck too.

Answer (score 3):

#### Use Binary field

Case insensivity problem in Microsoft Access was long time ago addressed in article **KB244693** published by Microsoft and [still can be found in Web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20040624043359/http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q244693).

Basically, the solution is to add a Binary field into your MS Access table and that one is finally case sensitive (uses Unicode for storing binary content) and still can be used as a text field with operators `=`, `LIKE` etc.

The field of type Binary cannot be added via the UI, but you add it to your existing table using SQL statement like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
  ADD COLUMN BinaryField1 BINARY(50)
```

Then you can manage it normally via the Access UI.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as such.