# MS Access cannot save both i and ɪ in table

Tags: ms-access

I have a table of IPA characters where the IPA character is being stored as Short Text in the field (no duplicates). I cannot store i AND ɪ in this field as MS Access thinks they are the same. Is there a way to be able to save these to the DB table in MS Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the answer here:

[Are unique indices on Access text fields always case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56823652/3527297)

but please note, that the *newer answer by miroxlav* is the correct answer.

**Addendum:**

To convert to a string:

```
Text = CStr([BinaryField1])
```

However, this will be zero-filled, thus the length of *Text* will always be `size_of_field / 2`.

To obtain the net length, first replace the zero characters with a space:

```
TrueText: Replace(CStr([BinaryField1]),Chr(0),"")
```

or, in code:

```
TrueText = Replace(CStr([BinaryField1]), vbNullChar, "")
```

Then the net length of TrueText can be obtained.

Comment: I used the suggestion to create a binary field to hold some text, however I ran into another problem. Previously the field was a string and I was using a calculated field to get the length of the string. Now I cannot use the new binary field in a calculated field. Is there any way to get around this? All I am doing in the calculated field is saving the length of the string i.e. if the string is 'abc' then length is 3.

Comment: Yes, see extended answer, please.